# Next Js Auth with Laravel 9 getting 500 Server Error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum, laravel-9

I'm trying to create a simple authentication system using Laravel 9 Sanctum and NextJs. I've created the API using Laravel 9 and also created the NextJs App. Everything is working fine in localhost but as I host NextJs App in Vercel then after login it does not redirect to the profile page showing 500 Internal Server Error.

This is my profile.js page in NextJs

```
import React from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
    const token = req.cookies.token;
    if (!token) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: "/",
                permanent: false,
            },
        };
    }

    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/profile`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
    });
    const jsonData = await response.json();

    return {
        props: {
            user: jsonData.data,
        },
    };
}

export default function Profile({ user }) {
    console.log(user);
    const router = useRouter();
    const logout = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/logout`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Accept: "application/json",
                Authorization: `Bearer ${Cookies.get("token")}`,
            },
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        if (data.success) {
            Cookies.remove("token");
            router.push("/");
        }
        console.log(data);
    };
    return (
        <>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row min-vh-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <div className="col-lg-5">
                        <div className="card shadow">
                            <div className="card-header">
                                <h1 className="fw-bold text-secondary">Profile</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div className="card-body p-4">
                                <p>Name: {user.name || ""}</p>
                                <p>E-Mail: {user.email || ""}</p>
                                <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => logout()}>
                                    Logout
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

This is my AuthController of Laravel 9

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AuthController extends Controller {

    // register an user
    public function register(Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
            'confirm_password' => 'required|string|min:6|same:password',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'validation',
                'errors' => $validator->errors(),
            ], 200);
        }

        $user =  User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
        ]);

        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'no',
            'token' => $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->plainTextToken,
        ], 200);
    }

    // login an user
    public function login(Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'validation',
                'errors' => $validator->errors(),
            ], 200);
        }

        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'invalid_credentials',
                'errors' => [
                    'message' => 'Username or password is incorrect',
                ],
            ], 200);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'no',
            'token' => $request->user()->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->plainTextToken,
        ], 200);
    }

    // get profile of an user
    public function profile() {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => Auth::user(),
        ], 200);
    }

    // logout an user
    public function logout(Request $request) {
        $request->user()->tokens()->delete();
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Successfully logged out',
        ], 200);
    }
}
```

I've also checked the vercel function log errors here are the logs:

```
[GET] /_next/data/8oqyzMgguzr1EJTXd7ExY/profile.json
15:57:16:11
2022-03-15T10:27:17.240Z    275ff038-d670-48dd-92f7-0744fca294fb    ERROR   FetchError: request to http://localhost:8000/api/profile failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/node-fetch/index.js:1:64142)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:475:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  page: '/profile'
}
RequestId: 275ff038-d670-48dd-92f7-0744fca294fb Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

This is what I'm getting after successful login:
[image]

Comment: "_FetchError: request to http://localhost:8000/api/profile failed_" Is that the correct server name?

Comment: Yes, it is correct working fine in localhost but don't know why not working in vercel.

Comment: Is `http://localhost:8000/api/profile` meant to point to your Laravel API endpoint? That won't work when deployed to Vercel, you need to host your API somewhere and point to a public URL endpoint.